# How do I extract the individual tests in a test suite object and execute them one by one

Tags: python, test-suite

I have a test suite object that is run like this

```
suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover("./tests")
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

So there are a bunch of python files in the tests folder which contain a lot of methods which tests something.

I wanna run the tests one by one and identify each test somehow.

So I asked chat gpt , how to do this

It gave me this

```
for test_case in suite:
        for test in test_case:
            print(test.id())
```

but got this error

```
AttributeError: 'TestSuite' object has no attribute 'id'
```

The reason I want to go through the testsuite object is that I don't want to write the code to find each test file.

So if there is any way please help me

Comment: Why do you need to find each test file in the first place? why do you want to override the default test execution?

Comment: I wanna run only some tests based on what files were modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to drill down one more level

```
for test_case in suite:
    for tests in test_case:
        for test in tests:
            print(test.id())
```

Comment: I have another doubt, It doesn't show all the modules/tests when I print it for some reason. But when running unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
It runs everything

Comment: @RandomDude are all the tests in the same level? maybe you need to drill down to the modules under `tests` folder.